# Qt chart error: ASSERT: "width > 0.0" in file painting\qrasterizer.cpp, line 761

Tags: c++, qt, qchar

I got an error when using `QValueAxis` in `QtCharts`:

> ASSERT: "width > 0.0" in file painting\qrasterizer.cpp, line 761

This happens when the `QBarSet` values are all `0`.
I have this example with the minimal necessary code below:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtCharts>

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QChart *chart = new QChart;
    QBarSeries *series = new QBarSeries(chart);
    QBarSet *set = new QBarSet("BarSet", series);
    series->append(set);

    QValueAxis *valueAxisX = new QValueAxis(chart);

    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);

    for(int i = 0; i < 24; ++i) {
        set->append(0); //error
        //if I set like set->append(1) or anything just to make sure the values are not all 0, there will be no error.

    }
    chart->addSeries(series);
    chart->setAxisX(valueAxisX, series);

    QMainWindow window;
    window.setCentralWidget(chartView);
    window.resize(420, 300);
    window.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

My program will initiate the `QBarSet` dynamically from a `QMap`. Like this:

```
for(auto it = map.cbegin(); it != map.cend(); ++it) {
    set->append(it.value());
}
```

And the `QMap` is initiated to something like this when the program starts:

```
QMap(("First", 0)("Second", 0)...)
```

Sometimes the `QMap` will not add values due to the use of the program, then all the `QBarSet` values will be initiated to `0`. Then the program will crash because of that error. 
So how can I avoid this error when the `QBarSet` values are all initiated to `0`?

Comment: @codekaizer that's all the error I got. Just that, no other details and nothing else.

Comment: @codekaizer tried both of your ways, the error is still there

Comment: @BTW, the error only shows when all `QBarSet` are 0, maybe something wrong with there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error speaks:

> ASSERT: "width > 0.0"

You need a value greater than zero.

Also `QBarSet::append`,

> void QBarSet::append(const qreal value)

expects a `qreal` or `double` value.

Perhaps you want to set it to `0.1` initially:

```
set->append(0.1);
```

Comment: ah, maybe that's the only way. :/